# Signing a folder and/or contents with OpenSLL error

Tags: powershell, ssl, openssl, signing

I have written a Powershell script that reads the contents of a USB drive, reads files one by one and signs them in turn, generating a corresponding .sha256 file for each one.

I am having trouble getting this to either read files within subfolders or just to sign the folders on the root.

The command I am using to sign files is as follows;

```
C:\openssl\openssl.exe dgst -sha256 -sign $PriKey -out $path"\"$file".sha256" -passin pass:<passowrd> $path"\"$file
```

When it gets to a folder, it gives a 'Permission Denied' error (The user is a full administrator with full access to everything).

Does anyone know how I can get OpenSSL to either sign a folder (I realise folders are not conventional files) or to have Powershell read the contents of subfolders and sign the files contained there as per above?

I am relatively new to both.

Regards,
Jose

Comment: You can have PowerShell execute a command for each file in a directory. (Hint: `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Object`). Search for examples.

Comment: Rather than putting code in a comment, please instead update your question with what you have tried, any specific errors, and then delete the comment.

Comment: Thanks @Bill_Stewart, and yes, I've already included those commands.  The issue isn't so much the Powershell but OpenSSL which returns a 'Permission Denied' error for ANY folder, even though the permissions are set OK. I know the PS part is OK as I can get the contents of the subfolders by using 'Get-ChildItem -Directory $path'

Thanks, 
Jose

Comment: `openssl.exe` can't process a directory name _itself_ (that's meaningless semantically). You will need to use `Get-ChildItem` and pass each file name as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks. With that being the case I'll have to revisit the PowerShell component trying to read the subfolders and see where I'm going wrong.  Cheers.